# Glossaries bite microtype?

Tags: glossaries, microtype

Looks like `glossaries` doesn't like letter spacing adjustments: whenever I add `\textls` adjustments to a name in the glossary, the entry is no longer listed under its initial letter, but shows up under a 'Symbols' group in the glossary. Any solution or workaround is appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automake,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,
            protrusion=true,expansion=true,tracking=true,kerning=true,
            spacing=true]{microtype}


\newglossaryentry{ham}{name=\textls[-40]{ham}, description={goes with eggs}}
\newglossaryentry{eggs}{name=\textls{eggs}, description={pork}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[style=indexgroup]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't an issue that has to do with `microtype` and its `\textls` command per se. The same effect also occurs with "standard LaTeX macros" like `\emph` or `\textsc`.

If you add contents that isn't text to an entry, you may have to tell TeX/your index tool how exactly to sort the entry with `sort`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automake,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,
            protrusion=true,expansion=true,tracking=true,kerning=true,
            spacing=true]{microtype}


\newglossaryentry{ham}{sort={ham}, name={\textls[-40]{ham}}, description={goes with eggs}}
\newglossaryentry{eggs}{sort={eggs}, name={\textls{eggs}}, description={pork}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\printglossary[style=indexgroup]
\end{document}
```

[image: Glossary with "E" and "H" heading]

Comment: Ugh, please don't letterspace lowercase letters.